# Cascade file error loading

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, cascade, visual-studio-2013

I'm using the opencv [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) for face detection 
I have done exactly how they explained, and the code works fine but the part where the xml file should be loaded is giving me the error msg!

```
if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
```

I have the cascade xml files in my directory.

When I make these two lines as comments, the code works fine and the cam turns on but of course it doesn't detect my face!

Answer (score 1):

There's some hidden assumption here, that the program *starts* from the the same directory, where the cascade files are. That might not be so in your case.

I bet it runs correctly, if you specify an *absolute path*

```
String face_cascade_name = "c:/la/la/la/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

Same again for the `eyes_cascade`.

Answer (score 0):

when you have no error on path or absolute path, you should see whether your linking lib is error; probably you linking release lib in Debug configuration, or you put all release libraries and debug libraries in your project.